# ember modal dialog liquid fire

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am new to ember. Have use liquid fire to slide between pages. But would like to add a transition to my ember modal.

I'd like fade in - like this - http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/#/modals (see bottom of the page).

My code:
app/templates/components/hello-modal.hbs:

```
<div>{{salutation}} {{person}}!</div>
<div>{{input value=message class="modal-input"}}</div>
<button {{action "gotIt"}} class="done">Thanks</button>
<button {{action "change"}} class="change">Change</button>
```

app/components/hello-modal.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['hello-modal'],
  actions: {
    gotIt: function() {
      this.sendAction('dismiss');
    },
    change: function() {
      this.sendAction('changeSalutation');
    }
  }
});
```

step 3 ( as you can see from the example in link says):
'Call modal() within your router map, at whichever scope you choose and wire up any actions:'

Not sure I understand this. But I added it to my cupcakes router:

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {

            this.route('device');
            this.route('cupcakes', function() {
              this.modal('hello-modal', {
                withParams: ['salutation', 'person'],
                otherParams: {
                  modalMessage: "message"
                },
                actions: {
                  changeSalutation: "changeSalutation"
                }
              });        

    });
```

cupcakes.hbs

```
{{#link-to (query-params salutation="Guten tag" person="Stef") tagName="button"}}
    Try It
{{/link-to}}
```

controllers/cupcakes.js:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['salutation', 'person'],
  salutation: null,
  person: null,
  modalMessage: "bound text for modal",
});
```

Nothing happens when I click 'try it' on cupcakes.hbs And no error messages show in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `{{liquid-modal}}` to your *templates/application.hbs* file?

My application.hbs looks like this:

```
// templates/application.hbs
{{outlet}}
{{liquid-modal}}
```